# Google chrome cannot detect v4l2loopback device

Tags: google-chrome, v4l2, v4l2loopback

I'm trying to transmit my screen using **ffmpeg** and **v4l2loopback**, more when running the commands:

> sudo modprobe v4l2loopback devices=1 video_nr=2 card_label="Camera
> Loopback"

and

> ffmpeg -f x11grab -framerate 30 -video_size 1366x768 -i :0.0 -f v4l2
> /dev/video2

chrome does not detect the device in: **/dev/video2**, I tried everything to make it work, but chrome does not detect it, I tried to add the filter:

> -vf format=pix_fmts=yuv420p

but still nothing.

> Chrome: 87.0.4280.66 (64bit) 
> OS: LinuxMint 19.3 
> v4l2loopback: 0.12.3

If anyone can help me, thank you in advance!.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load **videodev** module:

> sudo modprobe videodev

Load **v4l2** loopback:

> sudo modprobe v4l2loopback devices=1 video_nr=2 exclusive_caps=1 card_label="ExternalWebCam"

**Important Details:** Chrome, only accepts buffers in **yuv420p** pixel format, which makes a lot of sense, since the cameras have this pixel format as standard.

Use example:

> ffmpeg -f x11grab -r 30 -s 1366x768 -i :0.0+0,0 -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -threads 0 -f v4l2 /dev/video2

This command, stream the screen to /dev/video2 device, created by v4l2loopback

Answer (score 1):

Note the parameter "exclusive_caps", necessary to work in Chrome, see my script as an example, it creates three cameras

```
#!/bin/sh

MODULE_OPTIONS="devices=3 video_nr=11,12,13 exclusive_caps=1,1,1 card_label=X_11,X_12,X_13"

rmmod v4l2loopback 2> /dev/null
modprobe videodev
insmod ./v4l2loopback.ko ${MODULE_OPTIONS}
```